# Detect duplicate by multiple properties of an entity using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to detect any duplicate object by its internal multiple properties, taken example:

```
class Person{
    String name,
    Integer age,
    String address
    
    //constructors
    //getters setters
}
```

Now, out of above 3 parameters, I want to check duplication using 2 params, those are {name and age}
I tried to achieve this using streams but seems there should be even simpler way using stream.

Current approach:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(new Person("name1", 10, "address1"));
personList.add(new Person("name2", 20, "address1"));
personList.add(new Person("name1", 10, "address2"));
personList.add(new Person("name3", 10, "address2"));

// Want to detect name1 and age 10 as a duplicate entry

Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Person>> nameAgePersonListMap = personList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getName(), Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getAge())));
// and later checking each element for size() > 1
```

Is there a further efficient way to determine duplicates in this use-case?

Comment: Not easy with jdk, but possible: https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-distinct-by. This is for de-duplicating a stream, I assume that's what you mean.

Comment: “Want to detect” and then? What actual result do you want?

Comment: @Holger, I want to check if there is any duplicate entities using multiple properties of class. And list them.

Comment: So the result is supposed to be a `List<Person>`?

Comment: Yes, List<Person> would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If the keys are not much of importance after this grouping and identifying the duplicates, you can perform the same as  :

```
Map<List<?>, List<Person>> nameAgePersonListMap = personList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> Arrays.asList(i.getName(), i.getAge())));
```

I said "much", because you can access the `key`s still, just that the specific attribute would have to be *cast* into its type to retrieve it, for example `entry -> (String)entry.getKey().get(0)` would give back the name used in the grouping.

So specifically useful when performing something like

```
personList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> Arrays.asList(i.getName(), i.getAge())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() > 1)
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        ...
```

Comment: Another approach of course could be to have a custom object with those attributes, equals, and hashcode implemented used for grouping keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect duplicates by providing a composite key, collecting into list and the filtering by the size of this list.

The composite key may be created using various options which are more or less equivalent:

- String concatenation: `p -> p.getName() + "|" + p.getAge()`
- as a separate wrapper class suggested earlier: `p -> new PairKey(p.getName(), p.getAge())`

Specifically in this case a `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>` may be used as we have two parameters to build the key:

```
List<List<Person>> duplicateByNameAge = personList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    p -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(p.getName(), p.getAge()), 
                    Collectors.toList()))
                .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(duplicateByNameAge);
```

Output:

```
[[Person(name=name1, age=10, address=address1), Person(name=name1, age=10, address=address2)]]
```

Comment: Alex, this is much simpler way to group by and check for any duplication and very neat! Thanks for the answer. But apart from detecting duplication, and if using this approach to maintain a map using multiple properties of class, then the key had to be re-constructed. That's the only drawback I see in this.

Comment: It seems, whenever a compound key is needed, someone comes up with string concatenation. While in this specific case, there is no ambiguity in the result string, string concatenation still is very expensive. Here, we also have int to decimal number conversion, an often overlooked expense. The `Arrays.asList(…)` approach of the other answer is much cheaper, a difference that will grow when considering even more properties.

Comment: With the edit, and using entries, you are restricted to group by only two attributes now. So something not very extensible, and you could have created a custom entity and implemented equals and hashcode for that to represent it extensibly as I'd mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679493/java-streams-detect-duplicate-by-multiple-properties-of-pojo#comment110845434_62680135) to my answer as well.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Comments are general suggestions on code/aspects that can be improved. The answer is valid enough for this use case. Maybe worth mentioning the extensibility part. Over to community members then to decide if they find it useful or not. An over to individual based on the responses, to keep or delete it. :) Thanks for making the effort still.